# Activity is not launching after clicking on Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am doing a program on `BrodCastReceiver`. So in my program when any event is received it is showing notification but after clicking on same notification, it is not launching specified activity.

Here is my code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Priority 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .build();

     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);
     PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

     mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);
}
```

Comment: did you set your pending intent into the ``builder``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a pending intent that will response to the click event to open the corresponding 
activity

try this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Priority 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .build();

     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);



}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Toast.makeText(context, "Priority 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!").setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            .build();

 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);
 PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder);
}
```

**setContentIntent(pendingIntent);** You need to set this while creating NotificationManager.

Comment: PendingIntent is missing in above code
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!").setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        .build();
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
 mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder)
```

Initialize pendingIntent first and set it during build.